# 8086 assembly language about log in and sign up account

Tags: assembly, emu8086, dosbox

For the login part is good, everything works well on that part. But for registering a new account part, it keeps showing the invalid message although I full all the requirements which are username cant be repeated and the length of username should be more than 5 letters.

Here is my code

Here is the problem that I facing now:
[image: Here is the problem that I facing now]

Although it's a bit long, I hope u guys can take time for looking at it. This is my assignment.

Comment: You're right, this is way too long.  You need to spend some time with a debugger to reduce this to something much smaller that's not branching the way you expect, without all the surrounding code.  i.e. a [mcve].  It's still a good idea to show the full context in case of a mistake in reducing it to a [mcve] that can run but doesn't do anything useful except branch the wrong way when you single-step in a debugger.  See https://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/ / https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/

Comment: When I'm writing something new, what I do is write a few lines, then run them, single step in the debugger.  When they're working, then move on to write a few more lines and do the same.  That way, you always know where to look for new bugs: the latest few lines added.  Keep the partial program working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### An unfortunate fall-through problem

> ```
>    call isValidUserName
>    cmp aX, 1
>    JNE oor4
>    mov si, offset regUser
>    call checkLength
>    cmp cx, 5
>    JBE oor5
>                          <=== All is well: Need to jump to `askPsw` here
>    oor4:
>        jmp invalidacc
>    oor5:
>        jmp invalidUserLength
>
> askPsw:
> ```

The code is missing a crucial `jmp`. For now the code falls through in *oor4* eventhough the new username is long enough.

Next code solves the problem and avoids adding yet another jump to the program (mainly by inverting the condition):

```
    call isValidUserName     ; -> AX=[0=NOK, 1=OK]
    cmp  ax, 1
    JNE  oor4
    mov  si, offset regUser
    call checkLength         ; -> CX
    cmp  cx, 5
    JA   askPsw
  oor5:
    jmp  invalidUserLength
  oor4:
    jmp  invalidacc
     
askPsw:
```